# Autofill combobox from userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am new to VBA and my problem that I'm struggling with is to autofill a combobox in my form. 
For example, my combobox has listed these values: 
"apple", "tree", "juice"
I'm asking how to make it search through my list and when I write "app" to provide me with the "apple" result.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

If Me.ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("11")
    Set ph = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("22")
Dim i As String

i = Application.Match((Me.ComboBox3.Value), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)

    Me.TextBox8.Value = ph.Range("D" & i).Value
    Me.TextBox13.Value = ph.Range("P" & i).Value
    Me.TextBox41.Value = ph.Range("B" & i).Value

End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim i As Integer

Me.ComboBox3.Clear
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem ""

For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("A" & i).Value

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I made a ComboBox with the items as shown below:

[image]

If I start typing `App` it looks like below, where it selected `Apple` automatically

[image]

So it does exactly what you are asking for by default.